# Почему чат-бот вк отвечает всем сразу

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пишу чат-бот для группы на питоне. Проблема в том что если один пользователь нажимает кнопку на клавиатуре то бот отправляет ответ сразу всем. Например пользователь нажимает кнопку "о факультете" и бот всем у кого с ним есть диалог отвечает "бла бла бла". Я думал многопоточность решит эту проблему, но тоже не помогает. Вот код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from threading import *

token = 'dc052153daa647a77f5c4e5342afcf3006c14e357a24988e5f9f06f85d32e0165b9d1181a390794baf56a'
authorize = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(authorize)

keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)
keyboard.add_button('Опрос-распределение', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
keyboard.add_line()
keyboard.add_openlink_button('Игра Квиз', link='https://pornhub.com')
keyboard.add_line()
keyboard.add_button('О Факультете', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
keyboard.add_line()
keyboard.add_button('О СибАДИ', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
users = {}

def write_message(sender, message, keyboard):  # универсальная клавиатура, переделать все под нее
    authorize.method('messages.send', {'user_id': sender, 'message': message, 'random_id': get_random_id(),
                                       'keyboard': keyboard.get_keyboard()})


def main(user_id):
    sender = user_id
    write_message(sender, 'фгбоу во сибади и все такое', keyboard)
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
            res_msg = event.text.lower()
            if res_msg == 'опрос-распределение':
                write_message(sender, 'Томское моторно тракторное училище', keyboard)
            if res_msg == 'о факультете':
                write_message(sender, 'бла бла бла', keyboard)
            if res_msg == 'о сибади':
                write_message(sender, 'кекно-мемный колледж', keyboard)




for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
        user_id = event.user_id
        temp = user_id in users
        if temp == False:
            thread = Thread(target=main, args=(user_id,))
            users[user_id] = thread.start()
            print(users)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import vk_api
import random

from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='token')
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 'group_id')

keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)
keyboard.add_button('Опрос-распределение', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
keyboard.add_line()
keyboard.add_openlink_button('Игра Квиз', link='https://pornhub.com')
keyboard.add_line()
keyboard.add_button('О Факультете', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
keyboard.add_line()
keyboard.add_button('О СибАДИ', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)


def send_message(event, message):
    vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.object.message['peer_id'], message=message,
                     random_id=random.random())


def send_keyboard(event):
    vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.object.message['peer_id'],
                     random_id=random.random(), keyboard=keyboard.get_keyboard(),
                     message='opa')


for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.object.message["text"] == 'о факультете':
            send_message(event, 'бла бла бла')
        elif event.object.message["text"] == 'clav':
            send_keyboard(event)
```

Comment: не работает этот код(

Comment: у меня все работает, покажите ошибку